# 'SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input' as a response to my EF query

Tags: json, .net-core

I am using .NET Core 2.2 MVC. I have created a Method to return a JSON as the response of a EF Query, but I am always receiving this error in the js side:

```
 SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input
```

The method is:

```
 public async Task<JsonResult> GetReverberoData(DateTime Start, DateTime End)
        {
            var data= await _context.Table1
                .Include("FurnaceTypes")
                .Where(x=>x.StartCast >= Start && x.EndCast <= End)
                .ToListAsync();
        

          return Json(data)

           

        }
```

And the ajax call:

```
var frm = $('#DateSelection');
        frm.submit(function (ev) {
            $.ajax({
                type: frm.attr('method'),
                url: frm.attr('action'),
                data: frm.serialize(),
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                    console.log(data.error);
                },
                error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                    alert(xhr.statusText);
                    alert(thrownError);
                }  
            });
            ev.preventDefault();
        });
```

If I replace in the GetReverberoData method return Json(data) by return Json(string), then it works perfect.

What am I missing?

Comment: try simply changing return type for your method to:
`public async IActionResult GetReverberoData(DateTime Start, DateTime End)`

Comment: The error continues

Comment: Then it might just be a corrupt json. Try to validate it using `using Newtonsoft.Json;`
`var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data);`